# Проверяемые исключения

Tags: java, исключения

Пусть есть метод, который может бросить проверяемое исключение при некорректных входных параметрах

```
void throwMethod(int count) throws MyException {
  if (count < 0)
    throw new MyException(...);
  .......
}
```

и есть вызывающий метод, который передает гарантировано правильный параметр

```
void callMethod() {
  int count = 15;
  throwMethod(count);
}
```

Компилятор говорит, что `callMethod` должен декларировать возможность возникновения исключения `MyException`. Т.е. у меня есть два пути: либо задекларировать это

```
void callMethod() throws MyException {
  int count = 15;
  throwMethod(count);
}
```

либо поймать его

```
void callMethod() {
  int count = 15;
  try {
    throwMethod(count);
  } catch (MyException e) {}
}
```

первый вариант мне не нравится, т.к. декларируется событие, которое никогда не произойдет. Во втором варианте закапываются грабли, которые могут всплыть при рефакторинге. Скажем, в методе `throwMethod` усилится проверка

```
void throwMethod(int count) throws MyException {
  if (count < 0 && count > 10)
    throw new MyException(...);
  .......
}
```

или вызываемый метод перепишется

```
void callMethod() {
  int count = 15 - List.count;
  try {
    throwMethod(count);
  } catch (MyException e) {}
}
```

тогда исключение потеряется и ошибку придется искать долго. Ну и кроме того, у меня стабильное отвращение перед пустой `catch` секцией.

Есть еще мысль, выбросить непроверяемое исключение

```
void callMethod() {
  int count = 15;
  try {
    throwMethod(count);
  } catch (MyException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

Тогда если сейчас исключений не может быть, тогда и `RuntimeException` не будет. А если что-то поменяется, то хоть ошибку увидим. Но это попахивает каким-то костылем.

Вопрос - как делать правильно?

**UPDATE**

Вопрос возник по мотивам конструктора класса `URL(String)`, который может бросить `MalformedURLException` если в строке не указан протокол, указан неизвестный протокол или передан null. И я создаю объект кодом

```
URL url = new URL('http://google.com/');
```

Comment: А сделать MyException непроверяемым не подходит?

Comment: Интересно получается, вы говорите, что исключение гарантировано никогда не возникнет, но в опасениях описываете случай когда оно всё-таки возникает. Разве это не является ответом на ваш вопрос?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov нет. Исключение поднимается в библиотечном методе

Comment: @iksuy Нет. Я говорю, что **сейчас** оно возникнуть не может. Но код имеет тенденцию развиваться и модифицироваться

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, да, именно из-за тенденции к развитию огромное количество try-catch блоков написано. Так что да, как написано в ответе, лучше всего в данном случае бросать в catch блоке непроверяемое исключение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  } catch (MyException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Так делать не красиво. Если вы допускаете что исключение лучше сделать рантайм, то сделайте свое исключение, которое будет расширять `RuntimeException`.

```
} catch (MyException e) {}
```

Так делать определенно очень, очень плохо. Как вы правильно рассуждали, могут быть трудновыловимые баги.
Так что, по моему опыту, лучше уж кропотливо обрабатывать все ошибки, даже если вам кажется что они возникнуть не могут.
Ну тут я бы сделал примерно так:

```
void callMethod() throws MyException {/* ... */}
```

А уже в методе, который делает ряд вычислений, включая вызов `callMethod()`, я бы сделал ряд блоков try/catch, в которых бы обрабатывались разные варинты исключительных ситуаций.
примерно так:

```
try {
    /* ряд методов и вычсилений */
} catch (MyException1 e1) {
    //обработка одного из исключений
} catch (MyException me) {
    //обработка вашего исключения.
} catch (Exception e) {
    //на всякий случай, если произойдет совсем неожиданное исключение
}
```

Comment: Отмечу как правильный. Просто потому, что самый детализированный

Answer (score 3):

Я бы бросал **RuntimeException** и в секции **catch** еще бы писал логи.

Answer (score 2):

Вполне нормальная практика ловить проверяемое исключение и бросать непроверяемое. Можно создавать исключение вручную, можно воспользоваться средствами библиотеки Guava: `Throwables.propagate(Throwable)`, она сама проверит нужно ли оборачивать исключение и если не нужно (это `Runtime Exception` или `Error`), то перебрасывает полученное исключение, не создавая лишних обёрток.