# Проверяемые исключения 2. А смысл?

Tags: java, исключения

Вопрос навеян вот [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618315/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) вопросом. Там мне все советуют преобразовать проверяемое исключение в непроверяемое.

А вопрос у меня такой: зачем разработчики Java придумали такой термин как `проверяемое исключение`? Какой от этого профит? Чтобы знать какой метод может выбросить исключение, а какой нет? Так любой метод может выкинуть какой-нибудь `NullPointerException` который все равно нужно ловить и обрабатывать? Так чем `NullPointerException` отличается от `IOException` который нужно обязательно декларировать в `throws`? Ни в одном, известном мне, языке, такого термина нет.

Единственное объяснение, которое я могу придумать это то, что при возникновении проверяемого исключения, объект находится в некотором предусмотренном состоянии, и при непроверяемом - объект может быть поврежден.

Comment: Непроверяемое исключение — это **непредусмотренная предметной областью** логическая ошибка. Поэтому этот тип исключений, в отличие от проверяемых, *может* быть проигнорирован приложением и поднят до системного обработчика, который аварийно завершит работу программы. Если же такие ошибки являются частью предметной области, то их можно указать в `throws`.

Comment: @Arhad но это указание никого ни к чему не обязывает

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос о проверяемых и непроверяемых исключениях довольно спорный и часто возникающий, особенно когда появляется куча новых API, которым они мешают нормально развернуться (те же стримы и лямбды, например). Поэтому рассуждать о правильности их ввода спустя больше чем 20 лет после появления языка уже не совсем правильно.

NPE непроверяемое просто потому, что может теоретически возникнуть в любой строчке. Деление на ноль потенциально охватывает все случаи деления целых чисел, а `OutOfMemoryError` может вылететь во время создания любого объекта. Аналогичные причины можно найти и для остальных исключений.

Comment: Я не спрашиваю почему NPE непроверяемое. Мне интересно, зачем нужны проверяемые, если, как Вы правильно заметили, исключение может возникнуть в любой строчке программы

Comment: @AntonShchyrov. Чтобы было "контролируемое" исключение, которое программа обязана обработать и не нарушалась стабильность работы программы. К примеру, если пользователь выбирает несуществующий файл, надо чтобы приложение не вылетело, а стабильно обработало тип ошибки и оповестило пользователя.

Comment: @АнтонМухин Ну и, что мешает реализовать это через непроверяемые исключения? Может у меня стоит глобальный обработчик ислючений где-то на 10 вызовов назад по стеку. Я что, обязан во всех 10 методов писать `throws`? Ну глупо же

Comment: @Zefick А зачем вообще их придумали? И да, я не считаю, что рассуждать неправильно. Т.к. ничто не мешает разработчикам в какой-нибудь Java 10 отказаться от этого механизма. Совместимость не нарушится, а костылей в коде будет меньше

Answer (score 2):

`NullPointerException` никогда не произойдет, если вы будете делать проверку на null. `IOException` - такое исключение может воникнуть, даже если вы постараетесь заранее определить, возникнет ли оно. По сути, это для программиста как "чистый код". Он делает более удобно и красиво архитектуру кода.
Т.е. если, к примеру, вы видите, что ошибку можно не проверять, делаете ее рантайм. Как-то так, я думаю.

Comment: Проверяемые исключения, вернее требования их перехвата, **загрязняют** код. Пример я привел в связанном вопросе

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Да, поэтому существует хорошая практика в некоторых участках кода преобразовывать проверяемое исключение в свое собственное, не проверяемое.

Comment: Эта "хорошая практика" выглядит как воркэраунд глупой реализации

Answer (score 0):

С помощью проверок в коде вы можете обеспечить чтобы никогда не было NPE а вот присутствие файла на жестком диске не гарантированно, его можно удалить, поэтому нужно нужно заранее обработать такие ситуации