# Язык C и способы информирования о результатах действий

Tags: c, исключения

Тема непростая и обширная, и я очень хочу как следует в ней разобраться, но в книгах информации мало, да и часто оказывается, что реальный опыт мало пересекается с теорией.

В языке **С** существует огромное количество способов сообщать о результатах действий и возникших ошибках. Сейчас в меня кто-то кинет тухлым овощем, возражая, что в **C** имеются только лишь <strike>примитивные</strike> коды возврата.

Да, только коды возврата... Но они используются очень по-разному.

Конечно, можно реализовать исключения, используя **setjmp**/**longjmp**. Но, как сказал Д. Ритчи: *Если тебе нужен PL/1, ты знаешь, где его взять...*

Вот варианты обработки результатов выполнения, которые мне встречаются чаще всего:

1. Функция возвращает код, который является отчетом о ее работе:

   ```
   const int r_code = some_func(a, b, c);
   ```
2. Или, например, функция возвращает указатель на созданный объект, а в случае, если объект создать не удалось, функция возвращает **NULL**, не предоставляя никакой дополнительной информации о причине неудачи:

   ```
   object *obj = object_create(a, b, c);
   ```
3. Так же, функция может возвращать указатель на созданный объект, записывая в заданное расположение детальный отчет об операции (а не просто дополнительную информацию об ошибке):

   ```
   information i;
   object *obj = object_create(a, b, c, &i);
   ```
4. Еще функция может использовать глобальную переменную текущего потока для предоставления информации об ошибке:

   ```
   FILE *f = fopen(a, b);
   if (f == NULL)
   {
       // Обработка errno()
   ```

И еще примерно бесконечное количество вариантов...

При написании кода часто приходится жонглировать различными способами обработки ошибок и информирования о результатах действий.

Мои вопросы:

1. Есть ли в **C** универсальный способ для всего этого? А если нет, то в чем причина?
2. Было бы интересно узнать, какие еще существуют подходы, в чем их плюсы и минусы?
3. Есть ли большая разница в сложности разработки/поддержки кода, который использует/не использует исключения? Речь идет не про исключения в **C++**, а про исключения в языках с полноценной сборкой мусора - аля **Java**.

Например, я некоторое время писал на **Java**, так вот, когда я увидел реальный промышленный код, в котором ловились и проверялись все исключения, какие только возможно, то я вообще не понимал, как это можно поддерживать и развивать, когда на 5 строчек библиотечных вызовов приходится писать **сотни** строк **try/catch/finally**... И при любой малейшей правке приходится перекапывать весь код, чтобы где-то в 100500 ветке обработки ошибки добавить поддержку обработки исключения, которого раньше не существовало.

Comment: Про Java звучит как-то странно. Проверяемые исключения - это беда, от которой постепенно начали отказываться. А все непроверяемые исключения **отдельно** параноидально обрабатывать, как правило, не требуется.

Comment: Любой более или менее крупный проект (**Java** или **C++** - не имеет значения) развивается в течении длительного времени. Из-за этого приходится поддерживать миллионы строк кода, либо же все переписать. Практика показывает, что в большинстве случаев предпочитают поддерживать, а не переписывать.

Comment: Не любой) Если приложение имеет нормальную модульную архитектуру и покрыто тестами, то совершенно не важно, что там делают миллионы строк вокруг, за границами рабочей области. А управление потоком с помощью лапши из исключений - это дурно пахнет.

Comment: Ну да. Вот у вас есть крупная система, состоящая из серверов, клиентов и прочего. И в этой системе имеется класс (или модуль), который отвечает реализацию пакета. Не важно, что делает этот пакет, это может быть пакет телеметрии или пакет еще чего-нибудь. В результате развития проекта или по причине употребления менеджером некачественных веществ, вам необходимо несколько изменить условия работы с пакетом. Например, вы ужесточаете контроль корректности пакета, добавив проброс еще нескольких исключений. После этого надо добавить еще исключений уровнем выше, а затем еще выше. И... Та-дааам)

Comment: В вашем примере похоже на то, что слои приложения слишком связаны. Работу с протоколом стоило бы оградить фасадом. Бизнес-логике почти наверняка будет глубоко наплевать, почему именно сломался транспорт - строчку в лог и сообщение в репорт, на единственном try-catch.

Comment: Еще (похоже на 2) в вашем списке) можно возвращать структуру (если она небольшая, несколько слов памяти), которая вместе с результатом вызова содержит информацию об ошибках. Кстати, в некоторых случаях эта же структура используется как аргумент для других функций модуля, которые могут использовать те же поля для сигнализации о ходе своего исполнения. В принципе это достаточно похоже на пункт 3) у вас.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробую ответить, хотя это и очень сложно, учитывая, кто спрашивает и как.

> Есть ли в C универсальный способ для всего этого? А если нет, то в чем причина?

Универсального способа нет. Рекомендованного к использованию нет. Почему так? все очень просто - это чистый си. Тут программист сам ответственный за свой код, никто не будет ему вытирать ручки и рот.

> Было бы интересно узнать, какие еще существуют подходы, в чем их плюсы и минусы?

В принципе были перечислены все обычные способы. Еще есть несколько методов

- забить на ошибки (очень часто применяется)
- использовать сторонний фреймворк (да, для си такое есть. К примеру [cello](http://libcello.org/learn/queries-and-pitfalls)).

> Есть ли большая разница в сложности разработки/поддержки кода, который использует/не использует исключения? Речь идет не про исключения в C++, а про исключения в языках с полноценной сборкой мусора - аля Java.

Сборка мусора имеет весьма относительное отношение к исключениям. И делать какие то умозаключения с изначально неверного предположения чревато странными выводами. Поэтому, даже не  будут обсуждать где лучше исключения или сборка мусора. Оставим это холивар-экспертам.

Но в жава с спецификацией исключений действительно беда. Нужно либо пробрасывать постоянно весь список допустимых исключений, либо писать базовый и не переживать. В с++ это также пытались сделать, но вовремя отказались (и сделали noexcept, который более понятный).

При разработке с исключениями самое главное, что сложно допустить ситуацию, когда программа пошла в разнос. К примеру, одна функция инициализирует объект, а вторая его использует. Если первая может вернуть NULL, а вторая этого не ожидает... то ошибку можно долго и нудно искать. С исключениями это придется обработать и дальше код не пойдет (но все равно, программист это должен закодить, само оно редко так бывает сразу и красиво).

Comment: Одно уточнение. В Джаве нужно пробрасывать не весь список исключений, а только проверяемые (Checked). Поэтому один из вариантов все проверяемые превращать в непроверяемые. Детали [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618315/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) В JDK постепенно уходят от проверяемых исключений и переходят на непроверяемые (см java.time)

Comment: да. так и есть. Вот только превращение их в "не проверяемые"  убирает всю красивую, но ужасно реализованную идею.

Comment: В чем же "красота"? Уведомить всех к чему готовиться?

Comment: это очень философский вопрос. По идее, список исключений как раз показывает, кто и где какие исключения обрабатывает, что бы не осталось "необработанных" или "хорошо не заинкапсулированных". Но как только обычный программист "строит разухабистую иерархию классов+иерархию исключений" (прямо по гепертрофированном ооп, класс на каждый чих), то у него появляются большие списки исключений, которые нужно аккуратно прописывать. А учитывая любовь java программистов к длинным именам, то двух-трех исключений уже бывает "достаточно". Поэтому, идея хорошая, но как всегда, реализация подкачала.

Answer (score 2):

Механизм исключений **очень** удобен. Он позволяет обработать исключение именно в том месте, где известно, как его обработать.

Пример: есть у вас функция записи в лог

Как вы ее пишете на кодах ошибок

```
int log(char* msg, int len) {
  FILE * f = fopen(.....)
  if (f == NULL)
    return FILE_NOT_OPEN;
  if (fwrite(f, msg, len) != len)
    return MESSAGE_NOT_WRITE;
  fclose(f);
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

Уже в таком коде вы теряете исходную ошибку. Файл не открыт. А почему? Не все байты записались. По какой причине?

Если вы результат функции `log` не обработаете сразу после вызова, то опять потеряете информацию. И получите, что-то типа

```
int doProcess(...) {
  if (log(...) != SUCCESS)
    return LOG_NOT_WRITE;
}
```

Чтобы не потерять код ошибки нужно иметь единую систему кодов во всей системе. Включая все используемые библиотеки.

Теперь как этот же код будет выглядеть на исключениях

```
void log(char* msg, int len) {
  try {
    FILE * f = fopen(.....);
    try {
      fwrite(f, msg, len);
    } finally {
      fclose(f);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new LogWriteException(e);
  }
}

void doProcess(...) {
  ......
  log(....)
  .....
}

try {
  doProcess();
} catch (LogWriteException e) {
  processLogFailed(e);
}
```

1. резко упало количество кода и **повысилась** читабельность
2. Мы обрабатываем ошибки на том уровне, где знаем и можем их обработать
3. Мы не теряем информацию об оригинальном исключении.

В своих программах я **все** апишные вызовы делаю так

```
HANDLE Win32Check(HANDLE res) {
  if (!res)
    throw new OSError(GetLastError());
  return res;
}

HANDLE h = Win32Check(CreateEvent(....));
try {
   .....
} finally {
  CloseHandle(h);
}
```

И напоследок - наличие или отсутствие сборки мусора никак не влияет на возможность использования исключений.

Comment: Исключения никак не решают проблему версионируемости ошибок, более того, они ее даже усложняют. Конечно, в языках с полноценной сборкой мусора исключения предоставляют достаточно много преимуществ перед кодами ошибок, но и у исключений есть недостатки, причем весьма весомые. За использование же исключений в **C++** нужно *арестовывать*, потому что с реальным кодом исключения **C++** не совместимы.

Comment: К тому же исключения - ультра медленные и ультра прожорливые. Даже очень мощная железка захлебнется, если вы будете кидать исключения вместо кодов возврата в участке кода, который должен выполняться **много** раз в секунду: это обучение нейронных сетей, очереди, буферизация, многопоточная серверная обработка, шифрование и всякие другие алгоритмы.

Comment: два коментария и оба полны предрасудков... Арестовывать нужно за использование исключений без нужды. А просто за использование - нет.  Или Вы предлагаете Страуструпа также арестовать? (new то бросает исключение)

Comment: Именно из-за того, что **new()**, а так же **any_cast<>()** и *остальное*, бросают исключения из **откуда хочешь**, в **C++** нельзя использовать исключения. Вернее, можно, но ваш код превратится в крайне нестабильную лапшу. Я писал на **C++** достаточно, чтобы убедиться, что никто не умеет правильно обрабатывать исключения в этом языке. Даже в тривиальных случаях крайне-крайне тяжело сохранить валидность вашей программы после возникновения исключения. В случае же кода-мутанта (а-ля 99% существующего **C++** кода = шаблоны + виртуальные функции + множество предков + boost/stl) это в невозможно

Comment: @Максим Опять вы за сборку мусора. Каким боком она относится к исключениям? `Невозможно сохранить валидность программы` это почему? Чем в этом плане отличаются коды возврата? Вы о `finally` слышали? `Исключения медленны` - да. Но это **исключительные** ситуации. Если ваш высокопроизводительный код стабильно сыпет ошибки, то нужно убиррать **источник** ошибки, а не обработчик

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, на ваш вопрос, слышал ли я о **finally**, хочу у вас спросить, **читали ли вы вообще мой вопрос**? Судя по комментариям, у меня создается впечатление, что люди либо не читают мой вопрос, либо не плохо владеют русским языком. Мне показалось, что я достаточно ясно и четко сформулировал три вопроса.

Comment: Мы предполагаем, что `fwrite` в примерах не ломается? Иначе файл не будет закрываться же.

Comment: *Механизм исключений очень удобен* - категорически не согласен. Тот пример, который Вы привели - смая элементарная демонстрация бессмысленности исключений. Поясняю: в примере на С, достаточно проанализировать переменную erro при обработке ошибки и всё будет ясно. При использовании исключений, в Вашем примере, не только непонятно, что произошло, но даже непонятко - где произошло. От такого кода нет никакакой пользы...

Comment: В качестве противоположного примера предлагаю Вам подумать над решением **типичной** задачи: при запуске надо открыть три файла., при завершении - закрыть эти три файла. При этом, если не открывается первый - надо попытаться открыть его-же, но с другим расширением. Если не открывается второй - надо завершить  приложение. А если не открывается третий - начать ввод с stdin. Попробуйте написать это на *try..catch'  :-) А на кодах возврата я сделаю это элементарно.

Comment: @Sergey, **errno**, конечно, вещь удобная, но страдает от *проклятия глобальной переменной* - в тоннах кода довольно легко допустить маленькую ошибку или недочет, и вот уже в **errno** занесено какое-то левое значение. Очень непросто просчитать все наперед. И потом ищи, кто именно и когда это значение туда занес.

Comment: @Sergey Для этого обычно используют функцию `FileExists()`

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov *обычно используют функцию FileExists()* - совершенно не важно, как мы узнали, что файла не существует - с помощью этой функции, или из кода завершения *open()* - мой тезис в том, что в данной ситуации исключения только запутывают всё дело, а вовсе не помогают. Просто попробуйте набросать черновик решения задачи, которую я предложил, через исключения и вы сами всё поймёте.

Comment: @Sergey Я отлично понимаю решение этой задачи через исключения. Да. В данной конкретной ситуации с кодами возврата проще. Но с другой стороны если вы **ожидаете** отсутствия файла, то это уже не **исключительная** ситуация